# Hive count elements of the max partition column

Tags: hive, hive-partitions

I'm struggling with a query that may look simple but which is causing me a lot of trouble.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable where partition_column IN (SELECT MAX(partition_column) FROM mytable )
```

mytable is a 2To Hive External table, partitioned by the column partition_column. This query is taking 10 minutes to run..

When I do 2 separate queries :

```
SELECT MAX(partition_column) FROM mytable
> 2020-06-29
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable where partition_column = '2020-06-29'
```

It works super fine and super quickly.

Am I missing something ?
Thank you

I'm on Hive 1.2.1 and Hadoop 2.7.3

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the subquery is taking long time to process. Since you are filtering on the same column and table as the subquery, so the reducer step is taking a long time to process. Hence resulting in slow running of the query.

You could improve your query by introducing CTE which will create a temporary result set. Something as below:

```
 WITH MY_CTE_SUBQUERY AS (
      SELECT MAX(partition_column) as max_pc FROM mytable
 )
 SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM mytable 
 where partition_column IN (Select max_pc from MY_CTE_SUBQUERY);
```

More on [hive CTE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Common+Table+Expression) in the official doc.

Comment: Hi @Rishu, no the subquery itself takes 2 seconds, I tried with your query, it did not change a lot of things :(